# Sending my own path to ROS Navigation stack, Where can I locate the 'internal' nav_msgs/Path in the code?

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

Does anyone know where I can find this 'internal' nav_msgs/Path in the code of the ROS Navigation stack?
Is it move_base.cpp? navfn_node.cpp? trajectory_planner_ros.cpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391560/sending-my-own-path-to-ros-navigation-stack,-where-can-i-locate-the-%27internal%27-nav_msgs/path-in-the-code?/) by [jjbecomespheh](https://answers.ros.org/users/55607/jjbecomespheh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is much easier in Nav2's distributed server design https://navigation.ros.org/. You can easily inject your paths rather than using the path planning algorithms if you like.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's `move_base.cpp`.

Specifically, it is as follows.

```
if(!tc_->setPlan(*controller_plan_)){
```

ref : https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/6e9de3f16c76329fc8d218189d90e4ebe51d61c2/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L851

`controller_plan_`'s definition is as follows.

```
std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>* controller_plan_;
```

ref : https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/4a3d261daa4e7eafa40bf7e4505f8aa8678d7bd7/move_base/include/move_base/move_base.h#L216

It is different from `nav_msg/Path`, but if you compare it to the definition of `nav_msgs/Path`, you will see that it passes the same information.

```
std_msgs/Header header
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped[] poses
```

ref : http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-24**:
Great answer @miura.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-11-24**:
@osilva Thank you!